# iOS subviews are not resized when iAD appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a viewController that has 3 views (+ adView). bannerViewDidLoadAd event is triggered properly and then I would like to resize my views in order to make iAd visible. However, views are not resized and console shows a message telling that iAd may be obscured. How to bring it then to front and resize views? Thank you.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) { //&& iniciBanner


        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

        [self.view addSubview:adView];


        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        //adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, adView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, adView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height);

        self.vistaB.frame = CGRectMake(0, adView.frame.size.height, self.vistaB.frame.size.width, self.vistaB.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height);

        self.vistaSocial.frame = CGRectMake(0, adView.frame.size.height, self.vistaSocial.frame.size.width, self.vistaSocial.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height);

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems everything is ok, so my best guess is that you forgot to connect the IBoutlets of your views with the Xib's UViews.

Comment: properly connected... strange! I am reading about similar known bug for iOS 5.1